# Can't install packages via pip or npm

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip

I'm trying to install some packages globally on my Mac. But I'm not able to install them via `npm` or `pip`, because I'll always get the message that the packages does not exist. For `Python`, I solved this by always using a `virtualenv`. But now I'm trying to install the `@vue/cli` via `npm`, but I'm not able to access it. The commands are working fine, but I'm just not able to access it. I think it has something to do with my `$PATH`, but I don't know how to fix that.

If I look in my Finder, I can find the @vue folder in `/users/.../node_modules/`. Does someone know how I can access this folder with the `vue` command in Terminal?

Comment: I can think of 2 solutions:
add `/users/.../npm/bin` to your `$PATH`
or remove it and try installing it again with `sudo npm install...`

Comment: for installing any package globally just use the **-g** flag; like if I want to install 'nodemon' globally then: `npm install nodemon -g` will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a `PATH` problem:

1) Open up Terminal.

2) Run the following command:

`sudo nano /etc/paths`

3) Enter your password, when prompted.

4) Check if the correct paths exist in the file or not.

5) Fix, if needed

6) Hit Control-X to quit.

7) Enter “Y” to save the modified buffer.

Everything, should work fine now. If it doesn't try re-installing NPM/PIP.